# Eclipse's Ant needs jsch

Tags: eclipse, ant

I run ant script file in my Eclipse IDE. File contains command `scp`:

```
<scp file="myfile.txt" todir="user:password@somehost:/home/chuck"/>
```

This line causes error:

```
Cause: Could not load a dependent class com/jcraft/jsch/Logger
       It is not enough to have Ant's optional JARs
```

Why my Eclipse's Ant does not have this class and where I can download requied library? How to know which library version is needed?

[image]

Comment: https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/scp.html points out "Note: This task depends on external libraries not included in the Ant distribution."

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ANT - Could not load a dependent class com/jcraft/jsch/Logger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21231283/ant-could-not-load-a-dependent-class-com-jcraft-jsch-logger)

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look here for JSCH http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/

There is a Download section where you can find a `.jar` (`jsch-0.1.54.jar` at time of writing).

Then you have to setup ANT buildpath to use this jar.

Comment: What is the right place to keep this jar? I found several places where Eclipse keeps it's common things - `plugins` and `configuration` with particular sub directories. Should I always use newest version of jsch?

Comment: at the same location than your other jars? For example in `WEB-INF/lib` for a web application.